# please help me set the height of a blank line in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am having some trouble here with manipulating the height of a line in this code.I have tried 3 separate types of code:

```
<p style="height: 5px"></p> 
<p style="margin:0; padding-bottom: 12px;"></p>
<div style="height: 12px;" </div>
```

I want to lower the size of the row that is highlighted in the image. None of the snippets above have managed to do it. If anyone has any other snippets, I would greatly appreciate the help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<p>` element that contains nothing except a non-breaking space. `<p>` elements are there to markup *paragraphs* and you don't have one.

If you want a gap between two paragraphs, then use a `margin-bottom` on the first one or a `margin-top` on the second one.

Comment: When I entered: style="margin-left:0in; margin-right:0in; margin-bottom:1in;" on the first paragraph of text, it did nothing. I tried adding "Margin-Top:1in;" to the second paragraph and nothing happened. I have a feeling the system just sucks.

Comment: @JosephFresco — Yes, that's the one I said you should delete.

Comment: Right, so I did remove the <p> elements that contained nothing but a nbsp, but when I added the Margin-Top or Margin-bottom to the "Example blurb" line or the "instructions" line, it didn't work.